# In Cassandra 2.2, Unable to Create Role containing Password

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh

Unsuccessfully trying to create a new role (formerly user) that can login with a password based on the new role-based access-control in Cassandra 2.2, following the docs from [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/role-based-access-control-in-cassandra).

Specifically the following statement provides the subsequent error:

`CREATE ROLE pam WITH PASSWORD = 'abc123' AND LOGIN = true;`

*InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager doesn't support PASSWORD"*

Context. Fresh Cassandra 2.2 install with 3 nodes. Table system_auth only has the following tables: resource_role_permissons_index  role_permissions  role_members  roles -- and contains no legacy auth tables which is a warning when upgrading.

Comment: can you log into your cluster using cassandra/cassandra?

Comment: Yes, default username/password works and that's the context when issuing the "create role" command

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IAuthenticator in your nodes? Switch to using PasswordAuthenticator to support using passwords.

Below taken from the page on CassandraRoleManager: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/auth/CassandraRoleManager.java

> Alternative IAuthenticator implementations may be used in conjunction
>   with  * CassandraRoleManager, but WITH PASSWORD = 'password' will not
>   be supported  * in CREATE/ALTER ROLE statements.

Comment: Good question. But in cassandra.yaml I have: authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator and authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

Comment: Hmm, usually AllowAllAuthorizer is only used with AllowAllAuthenticator and doesn't support any privilege-type work. Can you try using CassandraAuthorizer?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Unfortunately just switched to the CassandraAuthorizer with no change in error

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the authorizer, AllowAllAuthorizer should work fine with PasswordAuthenticator & CassandraRoleManager.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that problem is that the role_manager option is missing from `cassandra.yaml`
In this case, Cassandra initializes an instance of the default role manager (`CassandraRoleManager`), but it does it before the configuration has been fully processed. Specifically, it does it before the Authenticator has been set, so it doesn't get initialized with the correct options for `PasswordAuthenticator`.

Fortunately, there's a simple workaround which is to ensure that the role manager setting is added to `cassandra.yaml`:

```
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
```

The ticket for this in the Cassandra bug tracker is [CASSANDRA-10209](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10209). That indicates that the bug has been fixed in Cassandra 2.2.2 and 3.0.0.